# JQuery single click event on a group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following JQuery code to trap clicks on a single button:

```
$(function () {

    //Set up click event on the Remove button
    $('#ButtonRemove').click(function (event) {
    //Process button click event
    }
}
```

where the HTML itself is this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove" />
```

But one of my pages is generated dynamically, which means that it can have a variable number of `Remove Now` buttons, each having the following HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_01" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_01" />
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_02" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_02" />
...
and so on
```

So can I adjust my JQuery statement to catch all those buttons in one method?

**EDIT:** Wow. Thank you everyone! There're so many ways to do it. JQuery is very handy!

Comment: Generated dynamically by Javascript after the page is loaded, or generated dynamically by a server script when creating the page?

Comment: @Barmar: Buttons are generated on the server by ASP.NET script.

Comment: Then use one of the "class" answers.

Comment: re "jQuery is very handy": you asked for jQuery, but plain JavaScript and a bunch of other libraries would do just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use classname for the buttons so that you jquery selctor selects and applies the event to all matching the className.

### Js

```
$(function () {

    //Set up click event on the Remove button
    $('.btnRemove').click(function (event) {
    //Process button click event
    alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

### Html

```
<input type="submit" class="btnRemove" name="ButtonRemove_01" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_01" />
<input type="submit" class="btnRemove" name="ButtonRemove_02" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_02" />
```

And if these are part of dynamic generated content on the page using JS then you can use event delegation using `on` so that dynamically created buttons with this classname gets the event delegated from the parent or `document`.  I have mentioned document here but use the element that exists in DOM already which is the container.

```
    //Set up click event on the Remove button
    $(document).on('click', '.btnRemove' ,function (event) {
    //Process button click event
       alert(this.id);
    });
```

or

```
$(function () {
$('contanerSelector').on('click', '.btnRemove' ,function (event) {
        //Process button click event
          alert(this.id);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure! Use the [jQuery on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation:

html:

```
<div id="Buttons">
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_01" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_01" />
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_02" value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_02" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#Buttons").on("click","input",function(event){
  $(this)...
});
```

You can also use more specific selectors, for example `"input[id^='ButtonRemove_']"` will target all the button whose id starts with ButtonRemove_

Comment: Thanks. But how would I know the ID or name of the button that was clicked?

Comment: @ahmd0 Use $(this). I have included a link to the documentation.

Comment: @SpYk3HH what are you talking about??? For example this.id will give you the button id. Your wrapping comment doesn't make sense either...

Comment: @Christophe It's simple, you can't call on the id of the button and get an inner button! .on Doesn't work like that in Delegate form. It works as such `$(PARENT).on("event", "CHILD", func`. If you're going to use it dynamically as you suggest, then the buttons need a wrapper. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/qg7NA/)

Comment: @Christophe I see you changed your answer, that makes much more sense! :)

Comment: @SpYk3HH The wrapper has always been there! Check the edit history. In my example #Buttons is not the button id.

Comment: @Christophe LoL, mah bad, just an oversight,still upped ya one, good work! And i still think class names are the better to go here, just my opinion. less complication, more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Give each button same class or use type 'submmit'

```
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_01" class='classname' value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_01" />
<input type="submit" name="ButtonRemove_02" class='classname' value="Remove Now" id="ButtonRemove_02" />
...
```

JS using class

```
$(".classname").click(function(){

  ///your code
});
```

JS using type

```
$("input:submit").click(function(){

  ///your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. If you want to catch event for all submit buttons.

```
$(":submit").on("click", function() {
 // Carry on
});
```

But it seems like you are trying to select element that start with `ButtonRemove`. So

```
$("[name^='ButtonRemove']").on("click", function() {
    // This function will apply on the elements whose name start with "ButtonRemove"
});
```

Comment: No, not all submit buttons. If you're putting it this way, I need only the ones with the name or ID starting with `ButtonRemove_`.